# Implementing extensible code in C++

Tags: java, c++, modularity

I am currently busy with a project where the main focus of the application is to be extensible (allow 3rd party developers to write plugins / their own implementations of interfaces).

Until now, I have been using Java, and built the application on the NetBeans platform. This has works perfectly fine and is quite easy to implement.

However, the program is quite computationally intense, and must be run on a grid of computers. I think C++ might be better suited for massive computations like I need.

What I would like to know. Is there any libraries *like* the NetBeans platform for C++. Or would I have to implement everything from scratch (not that I mind, I just wat to know)? Also, how easy is it to write extensible code with C++ and implement something like an update center? This is stuff you get for free with the NetBeans platform. My experience with the using the platform is that it allows you to write very modular code, which is something I like. New modules can be installed independantly, while the platform provides discovery of services to find all the installed plugins / impementations.

Can this be done similarly in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you benchmarked your computations in C++ vs. Java to get an idea of what performance improvements you might gain by switching to C++? Sounds like you've got a lot of experience with Java/NetBeans and you'd be starting from scratch in the C++ world; are there sufficient performance benefits of switching to C++ to justify the effort of switching platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you have a look at the [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com). They offer a mechanism to create plugins. Have a look at [this free online book](http://www.macresearch.org/cross-platform-applications-using-qt) about Qt. Plugins are discussed in [chapter 21](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405558).

Comment: I should have linked to the second page of chapter 21, since the first page is about extending the Qt framework itself: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405558&seqNum=2

Comment: @bjoernz - The Qt Framework does look like a possible alternative. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Nico - now I am curious, why Qt is out of the question. :-)

Comment: @bjoernz - I don't understand your comment. I said it looks like a definitive alternative to the NetBeans platform. I will look into the Qt Framework. It looks promising :)  - Did I say somewhere it is out of the question?

Comment: @Nico - Sorry, reading before the first coffee is not my strong suit...

Comment: @bjoernz - lol yeah, I feel tou pain :)

Answer (score 2):

For modularity on binary level [Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) might be a good choice.

For autoupdate there is for example [Google's Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/) (Windows) or [Update Engine](http://code.google.com/p/update-engine/) (OS X)

Comment: You should probably point out, that Boost.Extension is not yet part of the standard release of the boost libraries. You can obtain it from http://blog.redshoelace.com/2008/07/latest-release-downloadable.html.